# Why does this term appear twice in the step of implicit partial differentiation?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, partial-derivative, implicit-differentiation

The textbook example gives an implicitly defined function of $$x^3+y^3+z^3+6xyz=1$$ It then walks through the first step of partial differentiation of z with respect to $x$:

$$3x^2+3z^2\frac{\partial z}{\partial x}+6yz+6xy\frac{\partial z}{\partial x}=0$$

Why does the 6xyz part become two things? If I'm partial differentiating with respect to x, why isn't it just $6yz\frac{\partial z}{\partial x}$ ?

Comment: What about the fact that there is no $\frac{\partial y}{\partial x}$? Doesn't that bother you?

Comment: I added clarification, this is just the step to find $\frac{\partial z}{\partial x}$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, it seems that the given relation allows us to define $z = z(x,y)$...So differentiating with respect to $x$ gives in fact
$$
3x^2  + 3 \frac{\partial z}{\partial x} z^2+6yz +6xy \frac{\partial z}{\partial x} = 0
$$

The term you are asking for is just the derivative of a product:
$$
(6xyz)' = 6y(x'_x z + x z'_x) = 6y(z+x z'_x)
$$